# How to have forEach available on pseudo-arrays returned by querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, dom

Something nice with plain javascript would be to be able to use `forEach`, `map`, `filter`, etc, on the items returned by `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementsBy*` etc.

This'd lead to less dependency on jQuery, and simply cleaner code. Right now, this is how we can do it, in an ugly way:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll(sel), function(el) {
});
```

This is... verbose.

Any way to be able to use `forEach` and the likes right away on the elements returned?

Comment: Why does everyone allocate an array (`[]`) instead of using `Array.prototype.forEach`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A naive way would be to do this if you tested on Chrome:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

This works. On Webkit. It doesn't on Firefox though. Because FF returns an HTMLCollection...

The most cross-browser way I've found:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
```

It doesn't work on IE8 and lower though, because they choke when adding properties to host objects prototypes.

Full list:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
NodeList.prototype.map = HTMLCollection.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;
NodeList.prototype.filter = HTMLCollection.prototype.filter = Array.prototype.filter;
NodeList.prototype.reduce = HTMLCollection.prototype.reduce = Array.prototype.reduce;
NodeList.prototype.reduceRight = HTMLCollection.prototype.reduceRight = Array.prototype.reduceRight;
NodeList.prototype.every = HTMLCollection.prototype.every = Array.prototype.every;
NodeList.prototype.some = HTMLCollection.prototype.some = Array.prototype.some;
```

Or, to please our dear Bergi (and also because it *is* cleaner):

```
['forEach', 'map', 'filter', 'reduce', 'reduceRight', 'every', 'some'].forEach(
    function(p) {
    NodeList.prototype[p] = HTMLCollection.prototype[p] = Array.prototype[p];
});
```

Considering the link to perfectionkills, it's mostly irrelevant there. The problem is that the DOM is mostly not behaving the same on browsers when extended. This modification is sane in all the browsers except IE <=8.

Comment: I'm missing the link to http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/. Also, please use a loop for your "full list"

Comment: I don't like to extend the dom.

Answer (score 6):

```
function forEach( a, fn ) {
    return [].forEach.call(a, fn);
};

forEach(document.querySelectorAll(sel), function(el) {
});
```

And many more:

```
function map( a, fn ) {
    return [].map.call(a, fn);
};
function filter( a, fn ) {
    return [].filter.call(a, fn);
};
function reduce( a, fn ) {
    return [].reduce.call(a, fn);
};
function reduceRight( a, fn ) {
    return [].reduceRight.call(a, fn);
};
function every( a, fn ) {
    return [].every.call(a, fn);
};
function some( a, fn ) {
    return [].some.call(a, fn);
};
```

Maybe you will need

```
[].slice.call(a)
```

in some situations.

```
function forEach(a, fn) {
    return [].forEach.call([].slice.call(a), fn);
}
```

Comment: Uh, yeah, forgot to mention that. I'd rather use the `bind` method though (I don't remember off my head how to do it). But I still prefer the way shown in my answer out of these. It feels more "dommy".

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I think someone is rep whoring??

Comment: Nope. To be honest, the question/answer was for hat hunting. I honestly prefer the way shown in my answer. As said in my previous comment, I did know about your way already -- I just don't especially like it. Besides, why rep whoring when I'm already rep capped?!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like changing prototypes and want all array functions to just work, it may be easier to just convert your collection to an array:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'))
```

All array functions will be available, no need to update your code when new version of JavaScript is released:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(a => console.log(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` can now be used directly without conversions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList